# Headless Firefox selenium browser

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor, google-chrome-headless, firefox-headless

I have this `multiCapabilities` property in my `protractor.conf.js` file :

```
  multiCapabilities: [

    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      firefoxOptions: {
        args: ['--headless']
      },
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: [ '--headless' ]
      }

    },

    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--headless']
      }
    }
  ],
```

Chrome will run headless, but I cannot figure out the configuration to tell Firefox to run as headless, anyone know?

Comment: check this post once https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-run-protractor-test-cases-headless-mode-using-xvfb-selvaraj/

Comment: Is Firefox starting in regular mode or not starting at all?

Comment: Firefox is starting in "regular" mode, but fails to run as headless

Comment: What version of Firefox and what operating system are you on? BTW, this may be easier to debug over at irc.mozilla.org in #headless. I'm bdahl in that channel.

Comment: I don't really know how to use IRC, got any tips? :) Will figure it out